# How should property types be used correctly in class design

Tags: c#, class-design

Having two classes - e.g. Shop and Products

```
public class Shop
{
public int ShopId {get;set;}
public string ShopName {get;set;}
public ICollection Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
public int ProductId {get;set;}
public string ProductName {get;set;}
public Shop Shop {get;set;}
}
```

in the above code in Product class, when and why (if we should) use

```
public Shop Shop {get;set;}
```

instead of

```
public int ShopId {get;set;}
```

or vice versa?

Is the latter used for DTOs and the other mapping to db?

So I am really confused as to why and when we should use which. I am hoping someone clarifies this for me.

Comment: Same/similar question for Entity Framework: [EF foreign key reference using Id vs object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54787102/150605)

Comment: Thanks, thats a nice question too however it is specific to EF relations. My question is when designing my core class project that is isolated from any database and later be derived by other projects and manipulated for db mapping, should I still use the object property or the int.

Comment: @SubliminalHash Downvotes have a prescribed reason: unclear or lacks research. if you don't receive a comment indicating why your post was downvoted, and don't have any other context to rely on, you should assume one of those reasons.

Comment: This will end up being opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes down to the purpose of how you use the relationship. If you just want to store the data (save to DB, serialize to JSON) then you should go for ShopId. If you gonna use the shop in some business logic, you should go for Shop, because you don't want to keep loading the parent shop again and again every time.

Comment: Thank you.. Clears a beginners mind! For some people closing a logical question even if it is opinion based is the only status they will gain in their pathetic lives!

Comment: Haha, "opinion based", to me, it's relative term. For example, to solve a MVC routing problem, you got more than 3 different ways. Then, which way is better is also opinion based as well. So your question is more than valid.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe Your example _is_ a primarily opinion-based question, though. If someone asks "Which way is better?" that question cannot be definitively answered without knowing what the goal is — what "better" means, since that's a subjective term — so the proper response would be "Define 'better'." It's not hard to turn an opinion-based question like that into a (more) fact-based one by specifying shorter/faster/cleaner/more extensible/more secure/more resilient code is desired, but if the author can't be bothered to do that, then it absolutely should be closed as opinion-based, because it is.